# Functions with HTML codes and Sessions in JSP

Tags: jsp

Hi I am working on JSP. I need to have functions in JSP so that can implement reusage of codes. 
the stuff to be included in Functons are 
      1. Session variables.
      2. HTML codes - For page desiging depending on the condition check.
      3. the business logic - in JAVA

Can any one help me out on how to implement this and what tag to be used.

Thanks in advance
Malathy.L.

Answer (score 0):

Read these for JSP:

http://www.visualbuilder.com/jsp/tutorial/

http://www.jsptut.com/

This for a simple servlet example:

http://www.jsptube.com/